# Why printing multiple times on calling a function - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

I am calling a function from the controller scope, but in the console the values are printed three times. Why is this happening?

## SOURCE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModule" >
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-init="priceList='promo03,promo04'">
<div ng-controller="PricingController" >
    {{splitArray()}}
</div>
<script>
var myModule = angular.module('myModule',[]);

myModule.controller('PricingController',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.priceString = $scope.priceList;
    $scope.array = [];
    $scope.splitArray= function(){
        console.log($scope.priceString);
        $scope.array = $scope.priceString.split(",");
        console.log($scope.array[0]);
        console.log($scope.array[1]);
    };
}]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

## CONSOLE OUTPUT

```
promo03,promo04 
promo03
promo04 
promo03,promo04 
promo03 
promo04 
promo03,promo04 
promo03
promo04
```

## Expected Output

```
promo03,promo04 
promo03
promo04
```

Comment: may be digest cycle?

Comment: @Bhojendra Oh. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called for every digest loop of Angular.
If you keep your program running, you'll have even more logs.

To prevent it, call your function INTO your controller, not into a binded value into your html.

For instance :

```
$scope.splitArray= function(){
        console.log($scope.priceString);
        $scope.array = $scope.priceString.split(",");
        console.log($scope.array[0]);
        console.log($scope.array[1]);
    };
$scope.splitArray();
```